# Sync Facebook on different devices to avoid getting duplicate notifications

Tags: notifications, sync, facebook

My wife has two Android tablets, a Nexus 2012 and a Dell Venue. If after using one tablet for a few days, she uses the other, then she gets a lot of Facebook notifications which she already got on the other tablet.

Is there a way to keep the Facebook app on the those tablets in sync, so that any notification acknowledged on one doesn't appear on the other?